# Sum of characters to 1000

Tags: python

I'm working on project Euler's problem 17 where you should find the sum of the characters in all digits from 1-1000.
I came up with this solution (quite simple) but my answer is 100 less than the correct one and I can't find where I'm thinking wrong.
What mistake have I made?

```
units = len(str("onetwothreefourfivesixseveneightnine"))
first_tens = len(str("teneleventwelvethirteenfourteenfifteensixteenseventeeneighteennineteen"))
tens = len(str("twentythirtyfortyfiftysixtyseventyeightyninety"))
def total_to_hundred():
    sum = units * 9
    sum += first_tens
    sum += tens * 8
    return sum
def total_to_thousand():
    total = 9*7*100 #for "hundred"
    total += 9*3*99 #for "and"
    total += 10*total_to_hundred()
    total += 11 #for "one thousand"
    total += units*100 #for unit before hundred
    return total
print(total_to_thousand())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your first function:

```
def total_to_hundred():
    sum = units * 9
    sum += first_tens
    sum += tens * 10
    return sum
```

This fixes your problem. The issue was in your scalar multiple for the "tens" value.